# Generate webservice description with Swagger in Spring Webflux

Tags: spring, swagger, spring-webflux, springfox

Has someone a solution to describe webservice using Swagger library in a Spring webflux environment?

The goal is to use Swagger to generate the ws client stubs automatically.

Answer (score 5):

Work around until `Springfox 3.0.0` in not available

**Pom File**

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-spring-webflux</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

 <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-libs-milestone</id>
            <name>Spring Milestone Maven Repository</name>
            <url>http://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/oss-snapshot-local/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```

**Config**

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2WebFlux
public class SwaggerConfig  implements WebFluxConfigurer {
    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
       
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .genericModelSubstitutes(Mono.class, Flux.class, Publisher.class)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

        registry.addResourceHandler("/swagger**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");

        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    }
}
```

### **Update**

`springfox-boot-starter` is available now and it's work with webflux.
We just need to add below starter project in pom file.
Note: With  `springfox-boot-starter` in class path we do not need `@EnableSwagger2WebFlux`.

Remove explicit dependencies on `springfox-swagger2`

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${io.springfox}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks. Woudn't it be possible to just inject the ResourceHandlerRegistry ??? I will try

Comment: This solution was working for us initially. Suddenly it stopped working.

Comment: @RishikeshChaudhari updated the answer, Thanks for pointing out

Comment: IT DOES NOT WORK AT ALL>

Answer (score 3):

Spring boot 2.x and spring 5 features aren’t supported yet by springfox as of 2.8.0.

You might want to subscribe to the following Springfox issue: https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/1773

Answer (score 2):

While waiting for the official [webflux support](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/1773) from the springfox project, there is a workaround done by deblockt on GitHub: https://github.com/deblockt/springfox/tree/feature/webflux.

Just checkout the sourecode and build your own jars, include them into your project.

Answer (score 1):

As of release 2.9.2 you can use swagger with webflux.

https://github.com/deblockt/springfox/tree/feature/webflux

Answer (score 0):

I configured Spring boot 2 Servlet stack with swagger , project in github.
Better than nothing. :)
https://github.com/armdev/springboot2-swagger

Answer (score -1):

You can use spring-boot-starter-web along with spring-boot-starter-webflux. So if you really want to use swagger with spring webflux, then you must have to add spring-boot-starter-web depdendency into project. You can use swagger now exactly you have used with spring web. There won't be any difference.

Comment: If you include webflux and web starters, Spring will by default take in web and use the web mvc variant. This is not a good recommendation.

Comment: if you combine both spring starter web and webflux, you will be in danger.